# NodeJS : Object Prototype Event Handling

Tags: node.js, events, object, prototype

I've got the following code ....

#### Lib.js

```
var net     =   require('net');
var events  =   require('events');
var util    =   require('util');

app = module.exports =  function(){
    var name = "TestAPP";
    events.EventEmitter.call( this );
};
util.inherits(app,events.EventEmitter);


app.prototype.createServer = function(){
    net.createServer({allowHalfOpen:false}, this.listening).listen(8000);
    // I've also tried
    // net.createServer({allowHalfOpen:false}, app.prototype.listening).listen(8000);
}

app.prototype.listening = function(){
    util.log(this.name + ' > Server is listening.');
}
```

#### Test.js

```
var app = require('./lib');
var a = new app();
a.createServer();
```

But when I run it, the server is listening but the listening event doesn't fire.

I don't know if i'm missing something trivial. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistaken 'connection' listener for 'listening' listener. Check [this](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener) link.

```
app = module.exports =  function(){
    this.name = "TestAPP";
    events.EventEmitter.call( this );
};
util.inherits(app,events.EventEmitter);

app.prototype.createServer = function(){
    net.createServer({allowHalfOpen:false}).listen(8000, this.listening(this));
}

app.prototype.listening = function(a){
    util.log(a.name + ' > Server is listening.');
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Such a simple mistake! That just proves that I'm still a NodeJS n00b!